# How to call a specific attribute from a feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to store the coordinates of each points as an individual variable. How would I go about doing this?

```
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: studyArea,
  points: 5,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});


var roi = randomPoints.toList(5).get(0);

// var roi2 = [point geometry with coordinates]
```

Comment: `var roi2 = ee.Feature(randomPoints.toList(5).get(0)).geometry();`  Is this what you are looking for?